# Is there a way to keep alive request longer than 60s in EC2 instance?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Hello everyone I've been trying to execute our django app on amazon aws ec2 instance. Everything works fine except for requests longer than 60s. Those requests automatically get `504 Gateway Time-out`. I configured all needed ports in Security Groups for my EC2 instance.
We are using nginx and my nginx.conf looks like:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  3600s;

    client_max_body_size 500M;
    client_body_timeout 86400s;
    client_header_timeout 86400s;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    proxy_connect_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    send_timeout 86400s;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I tried to play with `keepalive_timeout` as many posts suggest but it's not working. There are also a lot of posts mentioning load balancer configuration but I'm not even using load balancer so this should not be related to it.

How do I manage my instance to process requests longer than 60s?

UPDATE:

Solved(as @jaygooby suggested) by searching `server { }` block inside django container. I modified `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydjango` and added `proxy_read_timeout 60m;` to my ````location / { }``` block.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after making the change? You need to restart it

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes I did restarted nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest tidying up your config first; you're setting some values without understanding what they're really for, then including another config file, then setting some more, and then including more config.

Change it so you do your includes and *then* override with the values you want.

I've annotated the various settings so you can see what they're for; these are so often cargo-cult copied in the hope they work. The only one that realistically needs to be anything like `86400s` (24 hours!) is `proxy_read_timeout`:

I suspect what's happening is that one of the conf files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` has a `60s` (or `1m`) setting for `proxy_read_timeout` and even though you were giving this a much larger value, you call the `include` again which will overwrite your setting.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    client_max_body_size 500M;    # Don't allow uploads larger than 500MB

    client_body_timeout 86400s;   # Defines a timeout for reading client
                                  # request body. The timeout is set only
                                  # for a period between two successive read
                                  # operations, not for the transmission of
                                  # the whole request body
    
    client_header_timeout 86400s; # Defines a timeout for reading client
                                  # request header; ie. the client's initial
                                  # HEAD, GET or POST

    proxy_connect_timeout 86400s; # Time to *open* a connection to the proxy
                                  # before we give up

    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;    # Timeout for transmitting a request *to*
                                  # the proxied server

    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;    # Timeout for reading a response from the
                                  # proxied server - did it send back 
                                  # anything before this has expired

    send_timeout 86400s;          # Timeout for sending a response to the
                                  # requesting client - note this isn't 
                                  # proxy_send_timeout, but the time between 
                                  # two successive write operations to the 
                                  # requesting client (ie. browser)
}
```

Comment: I checked /etc/nginx/conf.d/ and it's empty so all nginx settings come from the base nginx.conf. I also tried the settings you gave me but I don't manage to ride off this error 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: @Yusepp there's no `server {}` block in the above config, nor in the one you posted, so there must be one somewhere. Can you edit your question so you also include that (I guess it might be the `default` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: my ```/etc/nginx/``` (inside docker) looks like this ```conf.d  fastcgi_params  mime.types  modules  nginx.conf  scgi_params  uwsgi_params``` I don't find ```sites-enabled```

Comment: There must a `server {}` block somewhere - is the `nginx.conf` in your question the entire file?

Comment: I was modifying  ```/etc/nginx``` from my nginx container but not the one in the django container. Now I find a different  ```nginx.conf ``` and  ```sites-enabled``` with  ```server {}``` like: 
```server {

    listen 5002;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5003;
        }

        location /static/ {
                root /opt/app;
        }
        location /bundles/ {
                root /opt/app/dist/;
        }
        location /media/ {
                root /opt/app;
    }
}```

Comment: Just add a `proxy_read_timeout 5m;` to your `location /` block so it looks like this: `location / { proxy_read_timeout 5m; proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5003; }` - that should fix your 60s timeout (the nginx default) and set it 5 minutes instead.

Comment: Now It's working!!! thanks